# How to Sort DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, rows

i want to sort my datagridview as follows

[image]

When i clear any row the datagridview is like this

[image]

the resultant datagridview should be like this

[image]

i tried a little bit but it is not working

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                rw.Cells[i].Value = rw.Cells[i + 1].Value;
            }
    }
```

Comment: this is not sorting the gridview, it changes your gridview totally.

Comment: yes, like that only i want

Comment: Are you sure? you don't need data in single column?

Comment: There are so many columns, so how'll you know how long you need to sort?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, at any time only 12 columns and 8 rows.

Comment: `DataGridView` has a [Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z(v=vs.110).aspx).  Why not use that?

Comment: @Brian because he is not actually sorting anything, he wants to update the gridview cells totally and the view after that looks like being sorted. Just look at the 2 last screen shots he provided carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating your grid that way may have a poor performance especially when you have thousands of rows and dozens of columns. This code will work for you, however your want is really something strange and may not be encountered in most professional projects:

```
//First we need to get all the non-empty cell values in some List<string>
var cells = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              .Where(row=>!row.IsNewRow)
              .SelectMany(row=>dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                               .Select(col=>row.Cells[col]))
              .OrderBy(cell=>cell.ColumnIndex)
              .ThenBy(cell=>cell.RowIndex)
              .Where(cell=>Convert.ToString(cell.Value)!="").ToList();
//update the cells to make the grid look like sorted
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    if(dataGridView1.Rows[j].IsNewRow) continue;
    int k = i*8+j;
    dataGridView1[i,j].Value = k < cells.Count ? cells[k] : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: By using this my datagridview is not updating correctly the name will be like this "DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }" for first row ,"DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=2 }" like this it is updating

Comment: the above one i cleared, but it is taking only 7 rows instead of 8 rows.

Comment: the rowcount is fixed it is only 8 rows.

Comment: @Anjali see updated code, you are doing something very strange indeed. I have never done such a thing and also will never do.